# Plotly tooltip showing unicode character instead of letters in shiny server (R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have a shiny application running in a shiny server that started giving errors for all accented characters today (it was working with no errors until yesterday night).

I realized that all files seemed to be sourced using other types of encoding than utf-8. Thus, I tried forcing it using `source('file.R', encoding='utf-8')` , but this gives an error and the application doesn't run.

Since I could not find the reason to why this was happening, I changed all characters to their unicode format (\u00xx) and used the `enc2utf8` where needed.

After doing this, most of the application seemed to be working fine. The only problem that I am having now, is that the tooltip of my plotly charts started showing the unicode value instead of the character as shown in the image below. I tried not using the `enc2utf8` on those dataframes but it also showed the characters with errors. For example, it should be `Último` but it appears `<c3><9a>ltimo` when not using the `enc2utf8`.

[image]

How do I solve this problem? Is there a better way to force the files to be read in utf-8 instead of wharever encoding it is being read?

Extra information:

- In RStudio I am saving all files as UTF-8 by default, so I assumed the encoding should not be an issue
- In my local machine (windows) the application runs just fine and the plots are shown perfectly. The errors only occur on the server that runs in a linux machine

Comment: Try HTML entity characters.